# Homestead - automatic Windows hosts configuration

Tags: vagrant, yaml, hosts, homestead

[VVV](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV) uses the [vagrant-hostsupdater](https://github.com/cogitatio/vagrant-hostsupdater) plugin to automatically configure hosts. Is there a method for Homestead to do this after changing the Homestead.yaml file?

Comment: I think It would be hard to reconfigure hosts right after editing Homestead.yaml. However you can add/reconfigure hosts each time `up` command is executed. Essentially, Homestead is just a wrap for vagrant, so you can add [this piece of code](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV/blob/develop/Vagrantfile#L80) into [`homestead.rb`](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/blob/master/scripts/homestead.rb) file, but you need to tweak that `map` part to use yaml settings

Comment: Something like `hosts = []  settings["sites"].each do |site| hosts << site['map'] end` should work instead of that `hosts = paths.map do |path| ...`

Answer (score 1):

Add this, in homestead.rb

```
if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-hostsupdater") && settings["hosts_file_additions"] == true
     hosts = []
     settings["sites"].each do |site|
      hosts.push(site["map"])
    end
     config.hostsupdater.aliases = hosts
 end
```

Add this in Homestead.yaml

```
sites:
    - map: yourdevdomain.app
      to: /home/www/laravel/public
      hosts: 192.168.88.88

hosts_file_additions: true
```

You're done!
Here is the detailed tutorial  : https://aslamise.blogspot.com/2016/10/laravel-homestead-and-vagrant-hostsupdater-plugin.html